# How do I the rest of the string after a particular character in C

Tags: c, parsing

I want to get the rest of the string after the first "/" symbol.

The expectation I wanna get is:

**index/homepage/component.html/sdfsdf**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char link[] = "www.google.com/index/homepage/component.html/sdfsdf";    

    char *token;
    char *temp[1000];

    int i=0;

    token = strtok(link, "/");
    while(token != NULL){

        temp[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
        ++i;
    }



    printf("the parse string: %s\n",*temp);

    return 0;
}

the parse string: www.google.com
```

Comment: I think you need to read a little more about [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok). And probably a little about [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) and pointers and strings in general.

Comment: Probably use `strchr()`.  Probably don't use `strtok()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers have covered a more prefered method, that is `strchr()`, but for compleatness this is how it can be done using [regular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and sscanf.

this works by grabing everything befor the '/' and ignoring it by using %*[^/] (the * means it will not put it into a variable), then on the other side of '/' just getting everything till the end of line char is hit by %[^\n]

```
#include <stdio.h>

char link[] = "www.google.com/index/homepage/component.html/sdfsdf";   

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buff[128];

    // Seporate string after first "/"
    // %*[^/] goes untill it finds '/' and stops, but wont put it in a var
    // "/" will eat the '/' charater
    // %[^\n] goes untill it finds the '\n' char and puts it into buff
    sscanf(link, "%*[^/]/%[^\n]", buff);

    printf("%s\n", buff);
}
```

edit: added clarification of the '*'

Comment: Your use of `sscanf` is correct -- but `sscanf` does not use *Regular Expression* matching. Instead, the entire `Xscanf` family of functions uses predetermined *conversion specifiers* to handle character extraction. The `[...]` is just another conversion specifier for matching a nonempty sequence of characters and that also allows negating a match as well.

Comment: sscanf(recvline,"%[^/]", buff);     This line will get: www.google.com  -- %*[^/] goes untill it finds '/' and stops. What does the * do here. Sorry about my rusty memory about the reagex

Comment: Miracle, the * in this means that what ever is read by it wont be put into a variable. hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Since  you have one  target character you are after in a longer string, to find the first occurrence, you can simply use `strchr` to return a pointer to the desired character within the larger string. In this case the first `'/'`. To use `strchr` to locate the pointer associated with the first `'/'` your call would simply be:

```
char *p = strchr (link, '/');
```

If `p` is not `NULL` then it has been found within the string. Recall, the character found was a separator character that was not wanted, so you advance the pointer by 1 so that it is pointing to the first character after the `'/'`.

A simple call to `strlen()` at that point will tell you how many characters you must copy from `link` to your string where you are saving the results. Then using the length, you can simply call `memcpy` to copy from `link` beginning at the pointer location to the end of the string (including the *nul-terminating* character) to obtain the wanted characters. A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXTOK 2048

int main (void) {

    char link[] = "www.google.com/index/homepage/component.html/sdfsdf",
        *p = link,
        token[MAXTOK];              /* declare array to hold results */

    if ((p = strchr (link, '/'))) { /* check whether '/' found in line */
        size_t len = strlen (++p);  /* advance pointer by 1, get length */
        if (len > MAXTOK - 1) {     /* check if length exceeds available */
            fputs ("error: string exceeds allowable length.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        } 
        memcpy (token, p, len + 1); /* copy remaining part of string */
        printf ("%s\n", token);     /* output it */
    }
}
```

**EXample Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/charstr_rest
index/homepage/component.html/sdfsdf
```

Providing the desired result string. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: so for this one, strchr will go until "/" found, then we advance the pointer at "/" by 1. Then from there copy the rest of the string into token. And here we are copying the pointer or memory address into the array which is pointing to the remain character of the string. Am I understanding it correcly?

Comment: Since `p` is a pointer to the character after `'/'`, you can treat is like any pointer to a string (in this case it just to the "*rest of the string*"). So when you use `memcpy (token, p, len + 1);` you are copying `len + 1` bytes beginning at `p` to `token`. (you add the `+1` to make sure you copy the *nul-terminating* character). There is no need to use `strcpy` here because you have already computed the length of the rest of the string in `len`. Calling `strcpy` would just scan for end-of-string again before copying -- which there is no need for here `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this Helps..First find out the Position of '/' Character in the String then build your Substring,have mentioned on each block of code Whats it does...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char link[] = "www.google.com/index/homepage/component.html/sdfsdf";    
    char linktemp[50];
    int i=0,c=0;


    ////Finding the Position of First '/'
    for(i=0;i<strlen(link);i++)
    {
        if(link[i]=='/')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //If no '/' Character found
    if(i==strlen(link))
    {
        printf("No '/' Character found in the String");
        return 0;
    }

    ////Creating the Substring
    while(c<strlen(link)-i)
    {
    linktemp[c]=link[i+c+1];
    c++;
    }
    linktemp[c] ='\0';

    printf("the parse string: %s\n",linktemp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that code-only answers without any kind of explanations encourage [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is bad, and therefore such answers are really discouraged. Please take some time to read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your Suggestion,I had explained about how this works inside the code,and by the way now i have added explanation.